# Java Robot won't work when Chrome is in focus

Tags: java, windows, google-chrome, awtrobot

I'm having a weird issue. I'm trying to do some clicking with the robot class in java. All works fine except for when chrome is in focus.
This is my method:

```
public static void click(int X, int Y) {
    PointerInfo info = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    Point p = info.getLocation();
  //robo.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robo.mouseMove(X, Y);
    robo.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robo.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    System.out.println("Clicked at X: "+X+" Y: "+Y);
  //robo.mouseMove((int) p.getX(), (int) p.getY());
}
```

It just won't move or click when Chrome is focused. If I switch to notepad for example, it works.

Does Chrome have some kind of anti-macro stuff going on?

Thanks, have a nice day!

Comment: What does Chrome have to do with Java?  Are you developing an applet running that's inside Chrome?

Comment: I know it doesn't have anything to do with it or at least it shouldn't but it just won't move the mouse and click when Chrome is in focus. I can't figure out what the issue is. And no, it is not an applet.

Comment: Dunno, does the Java program still run when Chrome is in the foreground?  If your JVM is paused in the background it obviously won't run.

Comment: Yes. I'm doing the clicks inside a timer every 15 seconds, i have a countdown GUI that is always on top. If i switch to chrome, the mouse won't move or click. If i switch to teamviewer for example, or whatever other app, it will move and click. Very weird.

Comment: Sounds more like a Windows/Linux/whatever your platform thing is.  Chrome could be requesting some sort of exclusive focus, rather than a "normal" shared focus.  I know Windows and Java both have "full screen exclusive" mode, so perhaps Chrome uses something like that?  I'd ask again as a Windows question, you might get more info there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I suspected that Windows was the issue from the very get go since after the last reinstall i had some issues with it.
I had the same Windows from my hidden partition for 4 years now,reinstalling it every 4-6 months. Last week, when I reinstalled it, i had some permission issues, out of nowhere. I couldn't delete, move, copy, access stuff,etc. Had to play with ownership and stuff. Dunno where this came from, I didn't allow any windows updates thru. Unless it updated my hidden partition setup files, which I don't know if it is possible.

So last night I figured hey, lets activate the hidden Administrator account and see if the issue is still there. Well, it isn't. And now I went back to my normal account and all is fine now.

Short version: Enabled the hidden Administrator account on Windows 7, the issue is now gone on both accounts. Have a good day and thanks for your help!